# Is there a way to use an MS Access multiselect listbox control to filter records WITHOUT using VBA or iterating through the selected values?

Tags: ms-access, listbox, multi-select

I think the question speaks for itself, but I'll use a trivial example. Consider a table of salespeople as shown below:

[image]

Now consider a simple search/filter form with a list box where the user selects a region and it lists the salespeople in that region:

[image]

This is trivial. Assuming the list box is named `lstRegionFilter`, the query used to build the subform is simply:

```
select 
    [tblSalespeople].[SalespersonName] as [Salesperson Name],
    [tblSalespeople].[Region] as [Region]
from
    tblSalespeople
where
    [tblSalespeople].[Region] = [forms]![frmSearchForm]![listRegionFilter];
```

Now consider the list box is changed to a multiselection list box, so that the user can select multiple regions with the filter working accordingly, as follows:

[image]

While this can be done, every solution I've found involves a VBA procedure that iterates over the list box's selected items, constructs a comma-separated string, and feeds this string to the result query. This strikes me as being more work than ought to be necessary, and I figure I'm missing a simpler "built-in" solution, that **ought** to look something like this:

```
... where [tblSalespeople].[Region] in ([forms]![frmSearchForm]![listRegionFilter]);
```

or perhaps

```
... where [tblSalespeople].[Region] in (select * from [forms]![frmSearchForm]![listRegionFilter]);
```

The reason I figure there must be a simpler solution is because using a multi-selection list box to filter records would seem to be the most obvious purpose for the very existence of the multi-selection list box control in the first place. As such, it intuitively seems that there would need to be a built-in way of extracting the list box's selected values directly as a record-set-style object that would be natively understood by an Access query.

So, to make a long story short, my question is this:

***Is*** there a simple built-in way to do this without writing code to iterate over the list box's selected items?

Comment: No. -- Access has been around for quite some time. If every solution you find involves VBA, it is a strong indication that there is no other way.

Comment: @Andre Thanks. I suspected as much. The VBA approach is fine, but didn't want to use it if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: Won't change requirement for VBA to iterate listbox, but constructed criteria can be applied to form or report instead of modifying query object.